# How to access same TABLE using different procedure with good performance -- sql 2008

Tags: sql-server, performance, stored-procedures

I have 2 Procedures **Proc1,Proc2** which uses same tables **table1, table2, table3.**

So this is giving Performance issue.

I have used **WITH(NOLOCK)** for every table in Proc.

But If i run both Proc at same time Proc2 is getting executed after Proc1 .,

Say if

```
           Proc1 Execution time individually is 2 min,
           Proc2 Execution time Individually is 2 min

            Running both parallel 
            Proc1 is taking 2 Min , Proc2 is taking 4 Min
```

Which means Tables are getting LOCKED and released after Proc1.

**Why does Running parallel of 2 Procs which uses same tables is taking much time than running them individually.**

Thanks in advance

Comment: That test doesn't really prove anything. Longer time can be caused by many other causes.

Comment: In Real time i have 3 procs using same tables, i have tested it many time individually and running parallel, running parallel is taking much time its addition of first + actual.

Comment: Are your stored procedures only reading data, and not causing changes (updates/inserts/deletes) to the data?

Comment: @Dan    Its updating data

Comment: I thought so. It's not really possible to update data without locking stuff up. If you don't care about reading "dirty" data, consider using  [SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) READ UNCOMMITTED in the query that gets blocked.

Comment: @Pink If it's updating, it means it placing locks...

Comment: @Szymon what should i do to not to lock

Comment: You can't avoid locks when updating data. It's simply not possible! Check my answer below for a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have one transactions that alters the data (updates/inserts/deleted), then another statement that reads from the same table, will be blocked, until the first transaction is done.

To avoid this, set a proper transaction isolation level, on the select statement:

```
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED
```

But before doing this, make sure you understand 100% what it means.

More information here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Comment: Here My 2 Procs are UPDATING Data.., not select., so do i have any option for Update like select ???

Comment: Well, you can use `WITH (ROWLOCK)`, but be very careful, as this can quickly turn more resource intensive than the default table lock/page lock, ultimately causing everything to run even slower.